# Linux network connections logging

Tags: linux, ftp, http, performance-monitoring, network-monitoring

I have linux (OpenSuse) testing server and I would like to have detail log about http and ftp connections (and maybie other TCP connections).

Informations I'm interested in are  IP address, transfer speed, download size, date and time

What tools would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could log specific connections and then analyze the logs (with tools like "IPTables log analyzer", AWStats, logwatch and, with a little work, psad)

http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables  (LOG section)
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/force-iptables-to-log-messages-to-a-different-log-file.html
howto and examples

i don't think is possible to have straight information about transfer speed and download size. i will share my view below :
**download size** :

1. for http and ftp you have in their logs the date, ip and files transferred. so their size too. (you host those files isn't it?)
2. if the host machine is gateway and/or router you have to use a deep inspection (you could use a IDS like snort and create special rules)

**transfer speed**

1. generic speed benchmark : iptraf, iperf
2. pe connection : you could use monitoring tools like zabbix, nagios, ganglia etc (enumered in MY order of preference with primary criteria the easiness of writing plugins (IMHO, YMMV))

as a general rule: /var/log/* , grep, awk (and for those interested, perl) are your very best friends.
HTH

Comment: Linking to some articles is nice, how about writing a little bit about what can be done with the information should someone else be searching for something similar.  Your answer is good, but it can be better.